# Linking 3 spinners together

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm very new to android programming, I'm trying to create 3 spinners, these spinners will be in the form of country (122 units) province (10000) and district (15000) and when the country is selected, the provinces of that country will appear on the spinner and the districts belonging to it will appear on the spinner. or how can I add the district if and else make this situation very complicated. How should I use a structure? Thank you for your help
{

```
  spinnerIller = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinneriller);
    spinnerIlceler = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerilceler);

   
    dataAdapterForIller = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, iller);
    dataAdapterForIlceler = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ilceler0);

    
    dataAdapterForIller.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapterForIlceler.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

   
    spinnerIller.setAdapter(dataAdapterForIller);
    spinnerIlceler.setAdapter(dataAdapterForIlceler);

 
    spinnerIller.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
          if (position == 0) {
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.gri));
            
            if(parent.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(iller[0])) {
                dataAdapterForIlceler = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Register.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ilceler0);
            }else if(parent.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(iller[1])) {
                dataAdapterForIlceler = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Register.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ilceler1);
            }else if(parent.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(iller[2])) {
                dataAdapterForIlceler = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Register.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ilceler2);

            }


            dataAdapterForIlceler.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerIlceler.setAdapter(dataAdapterForIlceler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinnerIlceler.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {

                (TextView) view).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.gri));
               
            
            }
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: If possible, I'd create a map of integer key and list of strings. When ever you change the item on spinner X, load the items to the other spinners based on the ID of the relevant selectin

Comment: thanks i need more explanatory information